# Scripts getting added to my form with WFFM causing it to break

Tags: wffm

We got a build that has WFFM implementation and in a few forms we have been seeing some scripts being added to the end of the form. On all forms we see that the form doesn't load properly:
I have been looking to see if I can find where it's been defined. Anyone know where I should be looking for?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the code rendering those `<script>` tags in `\Views\Form\index.cshtml`:

```razor
@Html.RenderScripts(requirejs)
@Html.RenderScripts(main)
```

Removing these might break wffm ;)

Comment: thanks Gatogordo.
here is the problem. seems to be an environment issue. We have on one server a form which we don't see those scripts getting rendered. the form works fine. 
on the other server the same form, with those scripts blow up. Is there an option of including/ecluding those based on a condition?

Comment: Not that I am aware.. no code in the view would suggest it either

Comment: Are you sure that on the server where the scripts don't render the js files are available? Can you check the path as stated in the script src..

Comment: I double checked and you are right. They were not there because there was a conflict on that file and the version was older so this is why it worked on that server. When I set the file with the same content it broke there as well. What's still not clear to me is why...

Comment: this is native but makes the page break. probably js conflicts...

Comment: js conflict are very common with wffm..  at least your mystery is solved. Now you can start on the actual problem ;)